# Where is my web part? [MOSS]

Tags: web-part

A newly developed web part has been deployed to a half dozen site collections. We use one site collection for demo purposes. The new web part is available at all levels of that site collection, and works just fine.

In the main site collection, it is noted as as active web part in the root site of the site collection, but is not available to be deployed. In fact, some web parts that have been uninstalled are listed as available but are not actually there. Even the group heading (under which the new web part was installed) does not appear among those claimed for availability.

In short, the new web part does not appear to be available simply because the web part list does not include it (and has bogus entries). Rebooting the client machine hasn't done anything. Creating a new subsite hasn't changed anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Victor and James both state that you must "manually" take down the existing code in the gallery, but as our developer discovered, setting IgnoreIfAlreadyExists to FALSE (in the elements.xml file) allows the deployment to handle the replacement action.

I'm just adding this answer, to make that clear to future viewers of this thread.

Comment: Heh, just so happens I've been looking for an attribute that does exactly that in something I'm working at the minute :D

Answer (score 0):

Have the uninstalled web parts' .webpart files been removed from the gallery?

Does your web part development take into account the provisioning/teardown of the .webpart file in the gallery, as this will help remove inconsistencies between unavailable and listed web parts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to follow you, and I hope I get it right.

First of all you need to activate the feature which contains the Web Parts on each Site Collection so that the Web Parts appear in the Web Part Gallery.

The reason you see uninstalled Web Parts in the Gallery is that (by default) when a Web Part feature is deactivated, the entries (.dwp or .webpart files) in the Web Part Gallery is not removed. This is something that you manually have to do, or implement that logic in your feature deactivation code.

Comment: The feature is activated, and shows clearly among Site Collection Features (from the Site Settings interface). It just doesn't show when you attempt to Add Web Part.

I will investigate what both of you have noted about removing old code.

Comment: I've seen a similar issue a few times, when someone accidentally have broken permission inheritance on the Web Part Gallery catalog or manually fiddled with permissions on Web Parts in the gallery

Comment: The developer reports:
"Is because of this line in the elements.xml deployment file

<File Url="CQTickerWP.webpart" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE" Type="GhostableInLibrary" >

Comment: It's nothing wrong about that element, except that if you have IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE" you will not be able to update the file. Since it says GhostableInLibrary you will have a ghost file in the file system.